# Passing a set of parameters into UPDATE statement in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to passing a set of parameters into an UPDATE statement to reduce the length of my code. The code that works for me is as below:

```
cur.executescript('''

    UPDATE Summary

    SET Asset_ID = (SELECT ?
                    FROM ?
                    WHERE ? = Summary.Asset_PK_ID)

    WHERE Asset_ID IS NULL;

    UPDATE Summary

    SET Asset_ID = (SELECT BGA_Name
                    FROM BGA
                    WHERE BGA_PK_ID = Summary.Asset_PK_ID)

    WHERE Asset_ID IS NULL;

''')
```

However, I'm trying to change it to something like this:

```
input = [['Cabinet_Asset_ID', 'Cabinet', 'Cabinet_PK_ID'],
         ['BGA_Name', 'BGA', 'BGA_PK_ID']]


cur.executemany('''

    UPDATE Summary

    SET Asset_ID = (SELECT ?
                    FROM ?
                    WHERE ? = Summary.Asset_PK_ID)

    WHERE Asset_ID IS NULL;

''',input)
```

But I got the error saying: `"sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error"`.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I'm just started coding with python and SQL.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` can only be used in the `WHERE` clause but not for outputting columns or tables being selected from. You just have to format them as a string for each SQL statement with a loop instead:

```
input = [['Cabinet_Asset_ID', 'Cabinet', 'Cabinet_PK_ID'],
         ['BGA_Name', 'BGA', 'BGA_PK_ID']]

for column, table, key in input:
    cur.execute('''
    UPDATE Summary
    SET Asset_ID = (SELECT {}
                    FROM {}
                    WHERE ? = Summary.Asset_PK_ID)
    WHERE Asset_ID IS NULL;
'''.format(column, table), (key,))
```